# fetch="join" and hql

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

I'm quite confused about the fetch-attribute in a many-to-one mapping (class Order):

```
<many-to-one name="Product" column="ProductId" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
```

Now, if I write a hql-query like

```
from Order where Order.OrderId = x
```

Isn't Hibernate supposed to generate one SQL-Query, joining the Product? In my case, two queries happen and I'm not sure if the fetch-attribute within the mapping is ignored for some reason...

Comment: what happens with `session.Get<Order>(x)`?

Comment: in that case I get an expected join within the sql-query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL does not respect `fetch="join"`. You need to do it explicitly:

```
from Order o
join fetch o.Product
o.OrderId = x
```

(I might add `lazy="false"` is almost always a bad idea, but this will get you going)

Comment: So this is by design? Interesting, wasn't sure about this. Agree with you about lazy="false".

Comment: Well, I agree with the bad-idea thing. But sometimes I think it makes sense if we are talking about composition (and not aggregation or association)...